# Mysterious _UIParallaxDimmingView. What is it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I put a regular `UITableView` owned by a `UITableViewController` under `UINavigationController`.

Now, look at this code:

```
        [BGHPTools vDoForeGroundAndWait:^{
            PO(vi);
            PO([vi superview]);
            PO ([[vi superview]superview]);
            PO ([[[vi superview]superview]superview]);
        }];
        NSArray * arObjects =blarGetArrayTobeParsedWith(weakBODo);//No view object is manipulated here!!!!
        [BGHPTools vDoForeGroundAndWait:^{
            PO(vi);
            PO([vi superview]);
            PO ([[vi superview]superview]);
            PO ([[[vi superview]superview]superview]);
        }];
```

The code `blarGetArrayTobeParsedWith` simply download stuff from internet and for all display purpose, just do nothing and wait for a while

The first set of PO is like this:

```
2013-12-10 21:14:43.257 [8620:9407] vi: <BGTableViewWithBackgroundAndTopAndBottom: 0xd36d600; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x15d64320>; layer = <CALayer: 0x15d64890>; contentOffset: {0, -64}>
2013-12-10 21:14:43.259 [8620:9407] [vi superview]: <_UIParallaxDimmingView: 0x15f48a40; frame = (0 0; 320 480); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x15f79d00>>
2013-12-10 21:14:43.259 [8620:9407] [[vi superview]superview]: <UIView: 0x15850530; frame = (0 0; 320 480); layer = <: 0x15860480>>
2013-12-10 21:14:43.261 [8620:9407] [[[vi superview]superview]superview]: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0xcb35660; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xcb392f0>>
```

The second set of PO shows

```
2013-12-10 21:22:26.145 [8620:9407] vi: <BGTableViewWithBackgroundAndTopAndBottom: 0xd36d600; baseClass = UITableView; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x15d64320>; layer = <CALayer: 0x15d64890>; contentOffset: {0, -64}>
2013-12-10 21:22:26.145 [8620:9407] [vi superview]: <UIViewControllerWrapperView: 0xcb35660; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0xcb392f0>>
2013-12-10 21:22:26.146 [8620:9407] [[vi superview]superview]: <UINavigationTransitionView: 0x11cac940; frame = (0 0; 320 480); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x11cad190>>
2013-12-10 21:22:26.146 [8620:9407] [[[vi superview]superview]superview]: <UILayoutContainerView: 0x11ca8ef0; frame = (0 0; 320 480); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x11cb1070>; layer = <CALayer: 0x11ca69e0>>
```

It seems that vi, which is a `UITableView`, then changes its parent view.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_UIParalaxDimmingView`, judging from the name, has two purposes:

1. Dim content behind the wrapped controller
2. Add a paralax effect to the wrapped controller

I am not sure about your view hierachy but I would expect this kind of controller in the following situations:

1. Presented view controller
2. UIPopoverController
3. During specific controller transitions (animations)

If `blarGetArrayTobeParsedWith` downloads data from the internet, the difference could be between view hierarchy when animation is running and when animation has ended.