# How to deal with the UIParallaxDimmingView while pushing a view controller to another?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I need to make the UIParallaxDimmingView white or transparent.

vc1 has a white background is affected by this UIParallaxDimmingView making it kind of a light gray while transitioning to the vc2 after the animation is ended the vc2 get its white background.

I have made a research and I have found this code but doesn't work for me.

```swift
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, didShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    if (navigationController.viewControllers.count > 1)
    {
         self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = self
        navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
         self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.delegate = nil
        navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

[Mysterious _UIParallaxDimmingView. What is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20497061/mysterious-uiparallaxdimmingview-what-is-it)

[App freeze on ios 8 when push or pop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674279/app-freeze-on-ios-8-when-push-or-pop)

[iOS App Freezes on PushViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36503224/ios-app-freezes-on-pushviewcontroller/45419054#comment101201164_45419054)

**Update**
This was the initial question [How to remove UIParallaxDimmingView in pop UIViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48081742/how-to-remove-uiparallaxdimmingview-in-pop-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: any error with above code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No errors, the implementation is the only thing that appears to solve the problem but it doesn't address it. I added the code to the root of that navigation controller

Comment: you want to make it white ? sorry dear but your question is still little bit confusion for me to understand

Comment: yes I want to make it white or non color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Swift 5**

While pushing the viewController for example just remove the animation with false. easy peasy.

navigationController?.pushViewController(YourController, animated: false)

Comment: Is there other way to solve this while keeping the animation?

Comment: Looks like not yet pal

Comment: I hope they remove it or give us another way to deal with it...

Comment: Me too! perhaps soon, we need to keep looking into WWDC of next year at least.

Comment: any updates on this, do we have some solution on this while keeping the animations?